# NullPointerException During Maven Build

Tags: maven, maven-3

I cloned [this project](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/stash-webhook-plugin).

And I tried to build as it suggests in the readme, and I get these errors:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0-alpha-4:enforce (enforce-build-environ
>   ment) on project stash-webhook-plugin: Execution enforce-build-environment of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforc
>   er-plugin:1.0-alpha-4:enforce failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]

I think the only thing that's relevant might be the pom.xml and the maven version.

```
mvn-version
```

> Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T11:37:52-06:00)
>   Maven home: C:\Users\swalter\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin..
>   Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
>   OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

The pom.xml is visible in the bitbucket repo. I haven't done any modification and it doesn't work right after the clone. Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid. It needs to be Maven version 2.1.0 or you can just use the atlassian SDK command "atlas-install-plugin" to install the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I use old Scala version 2.11.8 and maven-scale-plugins 2.15.2, but new maven 3.6.3.when I build, After Checking for multiple version of Scala,it occurs NullPointerException.When I use maven 3.6.1.It is OK